# preg_replace_callback highlight pattern not match in result

Tags: php, regex, algorithm, replace

I have this code:

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog and lived to tell about it to his crazy moped.';
$text = explode("#", str_replace(" ", " #", $string)); //ugly trick to preserve space when exploding, but it works (faster than preg_split)
foreach ($text as $value) {
    echo preg_replace_callback("/(.*p.*e.*d.*|.*a.*y.*)/", function ($matches) {
        return " <strong>".$matches[0]."</strong> ";
    }, $value);
}
```

The point of it is to be able to enter a sequence of characters (in the code above it's a fixed pattern), and it finds and highlights those characters in the matched word. The code I have now highlights the entire word. I'm looking for the most efficient way of highlighting the characters.
The result of the current code:

> The quick brown fox **jumped** over the **lazy** dog and lived to tell about it to his **crazy** **moped.**

What I would like to have:

> The quick brown fox jum**ped** over the l**a**z**y** dog and lived to tell about it to his cr**a**z**y** mo**ped**.

Did I take the wrong approach? It would be awesome if someone could point me in the right way, I've been searching for hours and didn't find what I was looking for.

**EDIT 2:**
Divaka's been a great help. Almost there.. I apologize if I haven't been clear enough on what my goal is. I will try to explain further.

#### - Part A -

One of the things I will be using this code for is a phone book. A simple example:
When following characters are entered:

> Jan

I need it to match following examples:

> **Jan** Verhoeven
>   Ar**jan** Peters
>   Ra**j** N**a**re**n**
>   **J**ered Von Tr**an**

The problem is that I will be iterating over the entire phone book, person-record per person-record. Each person also has email-addresses, a postal address, maybe a website, a extra note, ect.. This means that the text I'm actually search can contain anything from `letters, numbers, special characters(&@()%_- etc..), newlines, and most importantly spaces`. So an entire record (csv) might contain the following info:

> *Name;Address;Email address;Website;Note*
>   Jan Verhoeven;Veldstraat 2a, 3209 Herkstad;jan@werk.be;www.janophetwerk.be,jan@telemet.be;Jan die ik ontmoet heb op de bouwbeurs.\n Zelfstandige vertegenwoordiger van bouwmaterialen.
>   Raj Naren;Kerklaan 334, 5873 Biep;raj@werk.be;;Rechtstreekse contactpersoon bij Werk.be (#654 intern)

The `\n` is meant to be an actual newline. So if I search for `@werk.be`, I'd like to see both these records as a result.

#### - Part B -

Something else I want to use this for is searching song-texts. When I'm looking for a song and I can only remember it had to do something with ducks or docks and a circle, I would enter `dckcircle` and get the following result:

> ... and the **d**u**ck**s were all dancing in a great big **circle**, around the great big bonfire ...

To be able to fine-tune the searching I'd like to be able to limit the number of spaces (or any other character), because I would imagine it finding a simple pattern like `eve` in every song while I'm only looking for a song that has the exact word `eve` in it.

#### - Conclusion -

If I summarize this in pseudo-regex, for a search pattern `abc` with a max of 3 spaces in-between it would be something like this: (I might be totally off here)

> (a)(any character, max 3 spaces)(b)(any character, max 3 spaces)(c)

Or more generic:

> (a)({any character}{these characters with a limit of 3})(b)({any character}{these characters with a limit of 3})(c)

This can even be extended to this fairly easily I'm guessing:

> (a)({any character}{these characters with a limit of 3}{not these characters})(b)({any character}{these characters with a limit of 3}{not these characters})(c)

*(I know the ´{}´ brackets are not to be used that way in a regular expression, but I don't know how else to put it without using a character that has a meaning in regular expressions.)*

---

If anyone wonders, I know the sql `like` statement would be able to do 80% (I'm guessing, might even be more) of what I'm trying to do, but I'm trying to avoid using a database to make this as portable as possible.
When the correct answer has been found, I'll clean this question (and the code) up and post the resulting php-class here (maybe I'll even put it up on github if that would be useful), so anyone looking for the same will have a fully working class to work with :).

Comment: You want to have one character between 'a' and 'y'? What is your purpose here?

Comment: It depends what rules you want to have. If you just want to find 'ped', wherever it's situated in the word and highlight it `str_replace` will do the trick, if you want it only at the end of the word you should play a little bit

Comment: The purpose is to be able to enter a sequence of characters, and it finds it in the words, position irrelevant, as long as they're in that order. An example is sublime text's autocomplete: in you type "paddr" in a css file, it will suggest "padding-right" and highlight the entered characters ("paddr") in the suggestion. That's what I'm trying to accomplish with php.

Comment: Did you try my answer already?

Comment: Just had time to test it and it looks nice, looks like you put some thought into this. There's a problem however, look at my edit.

Comment: I will try to suggest a solution of the problem later today, when I have more time.

Comment: Sure, take your time ;)

Comment: I've improved the code, so now the problem you stated is clear, and also matches chars appearing multiple times and make them red. Tell me when you test it. And still it's under 70 lines of code, heh :)

Comment: I've rewritten your code a bit, and used it to demonstrate how I mean to show the separate patterns in the result. I've put it up here: [link](http://joker.sinners.be/search.php) (this is a faculty server, so you might get a warning from cloud-based antiviruses due to little being known about them). I have, however, found another error: go ahead and search for `bb`. I'm guessing it's a regex problem.. So we're almost there! :)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that you will have two chars, also I think that the way you changed the code, the patterns are not right for the individual symbols. I will look at the code and see what I can do

Comment: Try your modified code with c,a,o - your code will highlight the sequence - which is not wanted behaviour. I will see what I can do later today, by then you could fix your modified code.

Comment: Do you mean this: [link](http://joker.sinners.be/search.php?s=cao) ? It creates a control for the pattern, but there's no erroneous matching. The control shouldn't be generated when there's no match, but that's something I will add later when everything works ;)

Comment: sorry, I was confused by the message in the search box. I will see what I can do with `bb` later

Comment: See my last edit. Hope everything to work as expected now.

Comment: Did you try the last version? Is it working?

Comment: I've edited the question. Thanks for effort you've put in this already! I won't be able to really test anything again until Wednesday, due to lack of time.. (got two exams)

Comment: @DaJF What you want is quite difficult for someone with limited regex knowledge. So it will be a "pain" to maintain for future developers. Further more, you've changed a lot from the initial question and added a part A and B. I suggest you to remove part B and put it in a separate question since it needs another approach IMO. Even part A is different from the initial question. The difficulty is mainly because you want to skip some characters. [Here's how you could approach part A](http://regex101.com/r/kT0xR3).

Comment: The problem with this pattern is that it would fail for [long sentences](http://regex101.com/r/jO9iE1) like in the initial question. The work around for that would be to limit it, so instead of using `.*?` we'll use `.{0,3}`. See [demo1](http://regex101.com/r/vJ7eH6) and [demo2](http://regex101.com/r/nZ7jT1). But if you used [this pattern with the example in part A](http://regex101.com/r/oX2nI4), it would fail for the last example `Jered Von Tran` Since the distance between `j` and `a` is more than 3. Which means there is a contradiction in your requirements.

Comment: As for part B. I'll give you an example why it doesn't make sense for "simple" regexes/computer algo's and that it requires way more AI (Artificial Intelligence). The way you provided the expected output is only logical for humans, why is something [like this](http://regex101.com/r/qN6yX9) not acceptable ? It does fulfil the requirements. The simple answer is "it doesn't make sense for us humans". I think you need to do some research on part B since it's not something you would figure out in 2mn. Fijne zondag :)

Answer (score 0):

I've came up with this. Tell me if it's what you want!

```
//$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog and lived to tell about it to his crazy moped.";
$string = "abcdefo";

//$pattern_array1 = array(a,y);
//$pattern_array2 = array(p,e,d);
$pattern_array1 = array(e,f);
$pattern_array2 = array(o);
$pattern_array2 = array(a,f);

$number_of_patterns = 2;

$regexp1 = generate_regexp($pattern_array1, 1);
$regexp2 = generate_regexp($pattern_array2, 2);

$string = preg_replace($regexp1["pattern"], $regexp1["replacement"], $string);
$string = preg_replace($regexp2["pattern"], $regexp2["replacement"], $string);

$string = transform_multimatched_chars($string);

// transforming other chars after transforming the multimatched ones
for($i = 1; $i <= $number_of_patterns; $i++) {
    $string = str_replace("#{$i}", "<strong>", $string);
    $string = str_replace("#/{$i}", "</strong>", $string);
}

echo $string;

function generate_regexp($pattern_array, $pattern_num) {
    $regexp["pattern"] = "/";
    $regexp["replacement"] = "";
    $i = 0;
    foreach($pattern_array as $key => $char) {
        $regexp["pattern"] .= "({$char})";
        $regexp["replacement"] .= "#{$pattern_num}\$". ($key + $i+1) . "#/{$pattern_num}";
        if($key < count($pattern_array) - 1) {
            $regexp["pattern"] .= "(?s)((?:(?!{$pattern_array[$key + 1]})(?!\s).)*)";
            $regexp["replacement"] .= "\$".($key + $i+2) . "";
        }

        $i = $key + 1;
    }
    $regexp["pattern"] .= "/";

    return $regexp;
}

function transform_multimatched_chars($string)
{
    preg_match_all("/((#[0-9]){2,})(.*)((#\/[0-9]){2,})/", $string, $matches);

    // change this for your purposes
    $start_replacement = '<span style="color:red;">';
    $end_replacement = '</span>';

    foreach($matches[1] as $key => $match)
    {
        $string = str_replace($match, $start_replacement, $string);
        $string = str_replace($matches[4][$key], $end_replacement, $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```